# How to have an incremented value of ordre each time I add a new row in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code to increment the ordre value:

```
$scope.addElement = function (_ordre) {

       console.log("_ordre 1"+_ordre);

       if(_ordre == undefined){
           _ordre = 0;


       if( _ordre == 0){
           _ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();

       }

       }
       console.log("_ordre 2 "+_ordre);

   console.log("_ordre 3 "+_ordre);


        var tmpElement = {
                  ordre:(_ordre === undefined) ? (parseInt($scope.finalOperationsList[$scope.finalOperationsList.length-1].ordre) + 1 ): _ordre,
                  temps : '',
                  designation:'',
                  disable : false
                 };   

        if ($scope.finalOperationsList.indexOf(tmpElement) == -1) {
          $scope.finalOperationsList.push(tmpElement);
          var t = parseInt(_ordre)+1; //_ordre is a string
          _ordre =t;
        }
        console.log("dern  "+_ordre);
  };
```

This is what I always get in console when I try to add a new row in my table:

```
_ordre 1undefined
 _ordre 2 1
 _ordre 3 1
 dern  2
```

The problem,is that when I try to add a new row in my table whith an incremented ordre each time,I get this result in console (I am stuck in 1 value of ordre)

So how can I correct my code please, to have an incremented value of ordre each time I add a new row ?

Thanks for help.

Update:
thanks zerohero Sir for your reply,but always the same problem,this is what I did according to your reply:

```
$scope.addElement = function (_ordre) {

       console.log("_ordre 1"+_ordre);

       if(_ordre == undefined){
              _ordre = 0;
        }

        _ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();

        console.log("_ordre 2 "+_ordre);

        _ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();
        console.log("_ordre 3 "+_ordre);


        var tmpElement = {
                  ordre:(_ordre === undefined) ? (parseInt($scope.finalOperationsList[$scope.finalOperationsList.length-1].ordre) + 1 ): _ordre,
                  temps : '',
                  designation:'',
                  codeOperation : 0,
                  disable : false
                 };   

        if ($scope.finalOperationsList.indexOf(tmpElement) == -1) {
          $scope.finalOperationsList.push(tmpElement);


        }
        console.log("dern  "+_ordre);
  };
```

I get always in rows "ordre" value equl to 2
miss I anything in the code??
thanks again for help

Answer (score 1):

This will only fire once, setting _orde to 1 when _orde is undefined:

```
if(_ordre == undefined){
           _ordre = 0;
       if( _ordre == 0){
           _ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();

       }
}
```

You then output this in succession:

```
console.log("_ordre 2 "+_ordre);
console.log("_ordre 3 "+_ordre);
```

Since no change was made to _ordre, it will show 1 in both instances.

The only time, you set _ordre to anything other than 1, is:

```
var t = parseInt(_ordre)+1; //_ordre is a string
_ordre =t;
```

And this happens after you set tmpElement's ordre to 1.

Your logic is very very flawed.

Do this:

```
if(_ordre == undefined){
      _ordre = 0;
}

_ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();

console.log("_ordre 2 "+_ordre);

_ordre = (parseInt(_ordre) + 1).toString();

console.log("_ordre 3 "+_ordre);
```

Comment: each row that I have add it to the Table, has an _ordre = undifined,so I should every time increment the value of _ordre before the adding of  a new row

Comment: you are passing _ordre into the function, I assumed _ordre is saved globally somewhere, if this is not the case, then _ordre will always start out as undefined, since it's not defined anywhere before the function call

Comment: yes Sir,_ordre is always undifined,when I try to create always a new Row,is there any way like local storage to save the state of _ordre if it's equal to undifined or 0 or 1 ...??

Comment: You can use $rootScope to store a value for _ordre and use that as the basis of your iteration